# How do I create a partial from this listing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following listing:

```
<% @backgrounds.each do |background| %>
 <tr>
   <td><%= background.image.url %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', background %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_background_path(background) %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to reuse this with other controllers. This is what I have so far:

```
<%= render partial:'image_listing', locals:{images:@backgrounds} %>

<% images.each do |image| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= image.image.url %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', image %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_image_path(image) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Is there a more generic version of edit_image_path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= render partial: "background", :collection => @backgrounds %>

# _background.html.erb
<tr>
  <td><%= background.image.url %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', background %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_background_path(background) %></td>
</tr>
```

If you call the partial with the same name of the object you want to iterate, the shortest form is

```
<%= render @backgrounds %>
```

If you can't follow this convention, use `:collection` and `:partial` options to instruct the rendering.

See [`ActionView::Partials`](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html).

Answer (score 0):

The generic version of edit_background_path seems to be edit_polymorphic_path. This makes the following possible:

```
<%= render partial: 'image_listing', locals:{ images:@backgrounds } %>  

<% images.each do |image| %>
  <tr>
    <td><img class='thumb' src='<%= image.image.url %>' /></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', image %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_polymorphic_path(image) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', image, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```